# When actually lord brahma shares the knowledge of vedas?

Tags: vedas, brahma, time

I am in a big confusion, please correct me if I am wrong in some points.

Almost in every religion there are stories about catastrophic end of this world/universe.

In Hinduism it is believed that there is a catastrophic end at the end of each kalyuga of every mahayuga. That means there are 996 catastrophic happen in each day of Brahma. Also there are 14 manvantara in each day of Brahma and for every manvantara 1 Manu is assigned.

In my point of view assigning 1 Manu for 1 manvantra signifies starting of an entirely new world this clearly proves a catastrophic happens before the assignment of Manu.

Also after the passage of 996 mahayugas (1 kalpa) the whole universe is destroyed. And again recreation happens when Brahma ji awakes from his samadhi kala. This cycle goes on until the age of Brahma reaches to 100 years.

In Vishnu Purana it is written that at the beginning (satyuga) Brahma ji with 4 kumaras himself shared the knowledge of vedas.

I want to ask the meaning of beginning here, is it satyuga of first mahayuga of this kalpa? or it is satyuga of this current mahayuga?,
or it is first satyuga of each manvantra?

In sort I want to ask, when actually Brahma ji shares Vedas? Beginning of mahayuga or manvantra or kalpa? The Vedas we are reading today is an outcome of how many catastrophic?

Comment: Good Question! IMHO Shri Laxmi Hayagrivar appears and gives vedas to Bramha, Bramha teaches this to his sons Kumaras, Rishis etc. Since these Bramha putras gods etc are replaced in every manvantara, this sharing of Vedas must be done in every manvantara.

Comment: The knowledge of `Veda` is shared by Maharshi `Bharadwaja`

Comment: Soon after Prakruta Pralaya , (On the First day /kalpa of Brahma ji)Sarga or Primary creation of (Subtle elements) is done by Lords Ikshana , thereon Prati sarga , secondary creation is done by Brahma upon every naimittika pralaya. I think it is the Satya Yuga of the first of 1000 chaturyugas (which maketh Brahma jis day) that tags the beginning of a kalpa

Answer (score -1):

And another sub question for this is what month is going on currently of Brahma ji? The current age of Brahma ji is 51 years so we're in 26th day of Brahma ji ( According to Matsya puran) so exactly in which month of their 51st year we're living in ?

Comment: t is better to post your query as a seperate question citing the above as a related one , instead of raising it in the ans. section of this question.BTW , we are in the Brahma jis 51st year (shweta varaha kalpa), 28th day , (first quarter of the kaliyuga.) .. So it could be the first month

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).